# Problem in reversing a string in assembly 8086

Tags: string, assembly, reverse, x86-16

I need to reverse a given string in assembly 8086. I wrote a code that should work but I get the output

> 'MAGSM$HIMI

instead of

> MAGSHIMIM

I can't figure out what is the problem with the code. I suspect the "$" is causing the problem but I have no idea.

My code:

```
 org 100h

jmp main    
    chrs db  'M','I','M','I','H','S','G','A','M', '$'


main:
    mov bp, sp

    mov ax,offset chrs
    call print_ax_str 
    mov ax, offset chrs
    push ax
    push 9
    call reverse
    PRINTN ;new line
    mov ax,offset chrs
    call print_ax_str 

    jmp stop

reverse proc
    ; First save the old BP  
    push bp 
    ; Now establish new BP 
    mov bp, sp  
    ;make space for 2 local variables
    sub sp, 4

    mov dx, [bp+6]
    mov bx, [bp+4] ;bx = 9
    dec bx         ;bx = 8
    add dx, bx ; dx = dx + 8    
    mov di, dx 
    mov SI, [bp+6] 
    mov cx, 4
    L1: 
    mov dx, [si]    
    xchg ax, [di]  
    mov [si], ax
    mov [di], dx 
    inc si        ;si--
    dec di        ;di++

    loop L1

    mov sp, bp 
    ; Restore OLD BP 
    pop bp
    retn 4 
reverse endp


stop:
    mov ah, 0 
    int 16h 
    ret

include magshimim.inc
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see if your code moved the `$`.  You only passed `9`, so a correct reverse function would leave the `$` in place and only reverse the 9 bytes before that.  But you're doing 2-byte loads/stores with AX and DX instead of AL and DL, so yeah you probably moved it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Now is that the final string i got is:` 'M', 'A', 'G', 'S', 'M' ,'$', 'H', 'I', M', 'I' `

Comment: Yup.  AX and DX are 2 bytes each.  That's your bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> chrs db  'M','I','M','I','H','S','G','A','M', '$'
>  ...
> L1: 
>  mov dx, [si]    
>  xchg ax, [di]  
>  mov [si], ax
>  mov [di], dx 
>  inc si        ;si--
>  dec di        ;di++
>  loop L1
> ```

The biggest problem here is that your *chrs* string contains bytes but your reversing procedure works with words (2 bytes).

Looking at this loop I suspect that you've mixed 2 solutions to the reversing problem. The `xchg ax, [di]` instruction tells this.

### Solution 1 using `MOV`

```
L1: 
 mov dl, [si]    
 mov al, [di]  
 mov [si], al
 mov [di], dl 
 inc si        ;si++
 dec di        ;di--
 loop L1
```

### Solution 2 using `XCHG`

```
L1: 
 mov dl, [si]    
 xchg dl, [di]  
 mov [si], dl
 inc si        ;si++
 dec di        ;di--
 loop L1
```

Please notice that the comments in your code were wrong. Incrementing `SI` corresponds to "si++". Similarly decrementing `DI` corresponds to "di--".

---

Since you pass the length of the string to the procedure and have the pointers based on it, you should also base your loop counter on it and not use a fixed count of 4 via `mov cx, 4`.

```
 mov cx, [bp+4]   ;SLen
 shr cx, 1        ;SLen/2
L1:
```

---

With some additional clean-up:

```
reverse proc
 push bp 
 mov  bp, sp
 mov  cx, [bp+4] ;SLen
 mov  si, [bp+6]
 mov  di, si
 add  di, cx
 dec  di
 shr  cx, 1      ;SLen/2
L1: 
 mov  dl, [si]    
 mov  al, [di]  
 mov  [si], al
 mov  [di], dl 
 inc  si        ;si++
 dec  di        ;di--
 loop L1
 pop  bp
 retn 4 
reverse endp
```